# Post in Spring Rest not working

Tags: java, spring, rest

This is the first time I am using REST with Spring, before this I always used JAX RS with Guice implementation.

Anyways here is  my Controller

```
@Controller
@Api(value = "Redis Data Structures Service", description = "Spring REST Controller that handles all the HTTP requests for the Redis Data Structures Service.", position = 1)
@ManagedResource(description = "Redis Data Structures Service REST Controller")
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableSwagger
@RequestMapping("/datastructures/v1")
public class MyResource{
   @RequestMapping(value = "/process", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes="application/json")
   public ResponseEntity<Operation> batch(@RequestBody Operation operation) throws JSONException{
       //this is just for testing
       operation.operationId = 123;
       return new ResponseEntity<Operation>(operation, HttpStatus.OK);
   }
}
```

Here is the Pojo of Operation class:

```
public class Operation{
   public int operationId;
   //get & set
}
```

Here is the rest call I am calling from Advance Rest Client Google chrome extension:

```
PATH : 
      <server:port>/datastructures/v1/process/
BODY : 
     {
       "operationId":10
     }
METHOD :
     POST
CONTENT TYPE : 
     application/json
```

And on calling this is the exception I am getting,

```
Required request body content is missing....with stack trace
```

Here is the stacktrace [click here](http://pastebin.com/9v5BSq7k)

its  really frustrating that this much simple call is killing the app, :) .
Please help, thanks in advance

Comment: do you have `jackson` in classpath?

Comment: please post the stacktrace.

Comment: I am using Spring boot, so I think Jackson is a default resolver of Json Strings in Calls, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @ankurverma ya. From your code i saw that your using both `@Controller` and `@RestController`. you dont need to specify `@Controller` when your using `@RestController`.

Comment: Please check the updated question added  the stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

I stripped away your `@Api` and `@EnableSwagger` annotations since I don't know which library they're from.

This code is working for me:

```
@Controller
@ManagedResource(description = "Redis Data Structures Service REST Controller")
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RequestMapping("/datastructures/v1")
public class Main {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/process", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes="application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Operation> batch(@RequestBody Operation operation) {
        //this is just for testing
        operation.operationId = 123;
        return new ResponseEntity<Operation>(operation, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

}
```

Using [HTTPie](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie):

```
$ http localhost:8080/datastructures/v1/process << EOF
heredoc : {
heredoc : "operationId": 5
heredoc : }
heredoc : EOF

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 27 Apr 2015 05:55:37 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{
    "operationId": 123
}
```

Spring boot 1.2.3.RELEASE

You do have both `@Controller` and `@RestController` on your controller which is unnecessary, but shouldn't be the cause of your issues. Check that you have imported the correct annotations.

Comment: thanks for the help, but still I am getting error please check the stacktrace once, I attached the pastebin link.

Comment: Spring isn't picking up your request body for some reason. Maybe you're doing something wrong in the Advanced Rest Client because your code should be working properly.